# Redirecting after a XMLHttpRequest

Tags: django, forms, redirect, xmlhttprequest, blob

I'm drawing on a canvas and then I upload the drawing to a database (Django). I have made this work by creating a Blob and sending a Form with XMLHttpRequest. But once uploaded, how do I navigate to the page that shows this new file? I would like the server to send a redirect, but that doesn't work and apparently that's not how you should do it. But how otherwise?

Here's the Javascript:

```
function submitFunction() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        form = document.getElementById('myForm');
        formData = new FormData(form);
        blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL);
        url = window.location.href;
    
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        formData.set('artwork_img', blob, 'artwork.jpeg');
        xhr.send(formData);
}
```

And here's the Django View:

```
def create (request, id):
    artwork = get_object_or_404(Artwork, pk=id)
    context = {'artwork' : artwork}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArtworkForm2(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newChild = Artwork()
            newChild.parent = artwork
            newChild.artwork_img = form.cleaned_data['artwork_img']
            newChild.artwork_title = form.cleaned_data['artwork_title']
            newChild.ancestors = artwork.ancestors+1
            newChild.save()
            newChild.updateAncestors()
# ---> this is kind of what I'd like to do:
            return redirect('showwork', newChild.id)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else: 
        form = ArtworkForm2()
        context.update({'form' : form})
        return render(request, 'exp/create.html', context)
```

Comment: What is the error with the code above ?

Comment: The client is not redirecting once the upload is completed.

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code that does the XMLHttpRequest?   You'll need to modify that code too.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have posted the JavaScript. You don't see it or is there something else you'd like to see?